# Spring batch 3600 partitions long pause before starting

Tags: java, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have the following spring batch job with a partitioned step that creates 3600 partitions for a partitioned step.  I use a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with a max pool size 100 and a queue capacity of 100 (although it seems to make no difference for speed).  Im using Visual VM to monitor the threads and I notice the taskExecutor threads don't start until > 5 minutes after starting the job.

Oddly enough,  If I limit the number of partitions to 100 the threads start fairly quickly and finish in about a minute.

Another issue I notice is that there doesn't seem to be more than one database connection ever as seen in the [VisualVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGV1H.png)  thread visualization

Can someone please review my batch job below and tell me if I am missing something that would limit the number of database connections to 1?  Also, why would adding more partitions affect the performance if my ThreadPoolTaskExecutor parameters don't change?  Shouldn't the jobs just sit in a queue until there is a thread able to service them?

--- Spring batch job ---

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd">


<context:property-placeholder location="${ext.properties.dataManipulation.Properties}"/>

<import resource="${ext.properties.dataManipulation.Connection}"/>

<import resource="flatFileLineProperties.xml"/>

<!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
</bean>



<util:map id="keys" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="SAILING_ID" value="ASCENDING" value-type="org.springframework.batch.item.database.Order"/>
    <entry key="RES_ID" value="ASCENDING" value-type="org.springframework.batch.item.database.Order" />
</util:map>

<!-- Here is my partioned step -->
<bean id="reservationsItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="selectClause">
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[ 
                    GUEST_ID,
                    FIRST_NAME,
                    LAST_NAME,
                    TITLE,
                    HOUSEHOLD_NAME,
                    SAILING_ID,
                    RES_ID
                ]]>
                </value>
            </property>
            <property name="fromClause" value="FROM RESERVATION "/>
            <property name="whereClause" >
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[ AND SAIL_ID = :sailId
                    ]]>
                </value>
            </property>
            <!--<property name="sortKey" value="SAILING_ID" />-->
            <property name="sortKeys" ref="keys"/>
       <!--<property name="sortKeys" ref="sortKeys"/>-->
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <!--<entry key="shipCode" value="#{stepExecutionContext[shipCode]}" />-->
            <entry key="sailId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[sailId]}" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <!--property name="pageSize" value="500000" /-->

    <property name="pageSize" value="40000" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.ncl.endeca.mapper.ColumnToHashMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sortKeys" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="prototype" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="org.springframework.batch.item.database.Order">
            <entry key="SAILING_ID" value="ASCENDING" />
            <entry key="RES_ID" value="ASCENDING" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<util:list id="client_fields" value-type="java.lang.String"> 
    <value>FIRST_NAME</value>
    <value>LAST_NAME</value>
    <value>TITLE</value>
    <value>HOUSEHOLD_NAME</value>

</util:list>

<bean id="reservationsItemWriter" class="com.ncl.endeca.writer.ReservationWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="guestFields" ref="client_fields" />
    <property name="outPrefix" value="${file.out.prefix}" />
    <property name="shipCode" value="#{stepExecutionContext[shipCode]}" />
    <property name="sailId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[sailId]}" />
    <property name="soldOutSailings" ref="soldOutSailingsList" />
</bean>

<bean id="yearsAgo" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>${yearsAgo}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="yearsAhead" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>${yearsAhead}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="resPartitioner" class="com.ncl.endeca.partition.ReservationPartitioner">
    <property name="yearsAgo" ref="yearsAgo" />
    <property name="yearsAhead" ref="yearsAhead" />
    <property name="batchLimit" value="${batch.limit}" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="${batch.corePoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${batch.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="${batch.queueCapacity}" />
</bean>


<!--<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>-->



<!-- each thread will run this job, with different stepExecutionContext values. -->
<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" >
    <flow parent="readReservations"/>
</step>

<!--<bean id="countrySpecificCompletionPolicy" class="org.springframework.batch.core.resource.StepExecutionSimpleCompletionPolicy">-->
    <!--<property name="keyName" value="sailId"/>-->
<!--</bean>-->

<batch:flow id="readReservations">
    <batch:step id="reservations" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" >
        <tasklet throttle-limit="${batch.corePoolSize}">
            <chunk reader="reservationsItemReader" writer="reservationsItemWriter" commit-interval="50000" />
        </tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:flow>

<!-- Actual Job -->
<batch:job id="dataManipulationJob">

    <batch:step id="masterStep">
        <batch:partition step="slave" partitioner="resPartitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="100" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

I have tried BasicDataSource and Hikari connections but the pool sizes have no affect when I monitor VisualVM

---- connection.xml ----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd">

<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 10 from dual" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="${hibernate.dataSourceClassName}" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${batch.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="${hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout}" />

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${dataSource.url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${dataSource.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${dataSource.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- HikariCP configuration -->
<!--<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">-->
    <!--<constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />-->
<!--</bean>-->

<!--<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" scope="step">-->
    <!--<property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.dataSourceClassName}" />-->
    <!--<property name="url" value="${dataSource.url}" />-->
    <!--<property name="username" value="${dataSource.username}" />-->
    <!--<property name="password" value="${dataSource.password}" />-->
    <!--<property name="testWhileIdle" value="false"/>-->
    <!--<property name="maxActive" value="${batch.corePoolSize}"/>-->
<!--</bean>-->

    <!-- connect to database -->
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@******" />
    <property name="username" value="****" />
    <property name="password" value="****" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The time to create partitions depends on the performance of your `ReservationPartitioner` as well as the number of partitions. Creating 3600 partitions means creating 3600 `StepExecution`/`ExecutionContext` objects and persisting them in the corresponding tables. This can take time for such a high number of partitions.

In regards to the database connection, you are using the `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` with a `ResourcelessTransactionManager` so there are no interactions with a database for Spring Batch meta-data. The only component that interacts with the database according to your configuration is the `JdbcPagingItemReader` (I don't know what is the type of your `ReservationWriter`) so it is not surprising to see a single database connection.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response.  Yes, indeed the only place I use a database connection is JdbcPagingItemReader but I thought that I would see multiple connection threads since the step is partitioned.  Is this not how the batch framework partitioning works?  I will read into the MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean